# Short notation for mapping to a family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to write a function of which the output is a family of sets over the domain.

Is this a correct notation?

$ f: A \rightarrow \{ A' | A' \subseteq A \} $

Is there a way I can shorten this, the way can shorten e.g. $ A \times ... \times A $ to  $ A^n $?

Comment: Your notation says that $f$ is a function that takes elements of the set $A$ to subsets of $A$: for each $a\in A$, $f(a)\subseteq A$. Is that what you intend? If so, $f:A\to\wp(A)$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $A$.  The power set of $A$, commonly denoted as $\mathcal{P}(A)$, is defined as $\mathcal{P}(A):=\{B~:~B\subseteq A\}$

Comment: Yes, the codomain is the power set of A. I didn't know I could write $ f : A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A) $